# What is the name of the this ODE: $y'''=xy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Just minutes ago I asked the wrong question. My apologies to the moderators.

If it was the second derivative instead of third then it would be the Airy equation.

The integral representation is simple to see through Fourier transform but I wonder if there is a name and solution for this type of equations. Actually, I am also interested in its general form:

$y^{(n)}=xy$

Here $n$ denotes $n$'th derivative.

Comment: $y'''=xy$ is a third order linear ordinary differential equation

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner I mean similar to the Airy equation does it have a name and applications that have already investigated.

Comment: Thanks for the edit MrYouMath

Comment: http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0412.pdf

Comment: The solutions are given as linear combinations of hypergeometric functions (checked for $n=3,4,5,6$)

Comment: Thanks to both Moo and Claude Leibovici